# Python Telegram bot - KeyError after running for a few hours

Tags: python, bots, telegram, keyerror

I wrote a Telegram bot in Python, which is running on my Raspberry Pi (Raspbian). I eventually see an error after the bot has been running for a few hours.

Before I post the complete code, could someone please help me understand the error? I would like to run the bot indefinitely, or at least for multiple days, before I need to restart it.

The error is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Schreibtisch/StreamrPreisBot/telepot/loop.py", line 37, in run_forever
    self._handle(msg)
  File "/home/pi/Schreibtisch/StreamrPreisBot/streamrinfobot.py", line 32, in handle
    command = msg['text']
KeyError: 'text'
```

Edit:
Following code is used:

```
def handle(msg):
    chat_id = msg['chat']['id']
    command = msg['text']
```

Might this code solve the problem?

```
def handle(msg):
    chat_id = msg['chat']['id']
    command = msg.get('text')
```

Comment: you should also post the code that produces this error.

Comment: I'd be happy to help track down the cause of the error if you at least post the code for `_handle(msg)` in `loop.py`.

Answer (score 1):

Error says there is no `text` key inside `msg` dict. Maybe it's some special telegram message that has no text or there is a bug in you code that delete `text` key in some cases. You could use

```
command = msg.get('text')
```

To get `None` when there is no text. Or

```
command = msg.get('text', '')
```

To get empty string (i.e. `''`) when there is no text.

You could also check that there is a `text` inside `msg` or not with `in` operator:

```
if 'text' not in msg:
    logger.error('bad message received!')
    return
```

---

If you want to your service to be always up you should add some mechanism for automatic restart.

like in Python to restart after any error:

```
while True:
    try:
        logger.info("Starting bot")
        run_bot()
    except Exception:
        logger.exception("Something bad happened. Restarting")
```

I also suggest to log errors in a file or services such as [Sentry](https://sentry.io/) to investigate why there is no text afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

A `KeyError` is raised when a value is requested from a `dict` but the key does not exist in the dictionary.

So, in your case, the `msg` dictionary does not have the key `text`.

You should inspect your code to ensure that the `msg` dictionary contains a value associated with the key `text`. Or, if you expect that `msg` will sometimes not contain the key `text`, you should instead access the dictionary with the `get` method, which never raises a `KeyError`. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) for more information.

Comment: @SurvivorX Before deciding to use the `get` method, you need to determine why the dictionary doesn't contain the `text` key. If you expect it to always contain the `text` key, then your bug is actually somewhere else. It just happens to be manifesting in this way. So, please tell me, do you expect the `text` key to _always_ be there?

Comment: Since the bot has permissions to read every single message in the groups it is used, the text key actually should always be given, I guess

Comment: @SurvivorX I see. So then it sounds like the source of your bug is elsewhere. Therefore, I would avoid the `get` method for now because it will silence the exception. Instead, try to track down the reason why the `text` key does not exist in the `msg`.

Comment: Actually the program is working perfectly fine, it just gives me that error (multiple times), after a few hours of runtime, and gets slower and slower. If silencing this Error helps, that would be enough already. I will let it run and check it tomorrow and respond here how it worked. Thanks!

Comment: @SurvivorX Any luck?

Comment: Using the get method actually helped, program is running and not crashing anymore. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @SurvivorX Please accept and optionally upvote the answer if it helped. Thanks!